# C++ - stringstream in a recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, stringstream

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void fRec(int i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return;
    }

    fRec(i - 1);

    ostringstream s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fRec(50000);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, this produces:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Backtrace from gdb:

```
#0  0x000000000040064f in fRec (i=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffc75a6f5c>) at strstr.cpp:6
#1  0x000000000040066e in fRec (i=28182) at strstr.cpp:11
#2  0x000000000040066e in fRec (i=28183) at strstr.cpp:11
#3  0x000000000040066e in fRec (i=28184) at strstr.cpp:11
#4  0x000000000040066e in fRec (i=28185) at strstr.cpp:11
#5  0x000000000040066e in fRec (i=28186) at strstr.cpp:11
...
```

I would like to ask why this is so - if I create a string object instead of ostringstream, everything finishes OK. It seems to me like if there could not be too many instances of stringstream at once?

Thanks for clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a stack overflow. The stack size for a program is usually limited. All you've determined is that `std::string` is probably smaller in size than `std::ostringstream` and so it doesn't fill up the stack as quickly. This is one of the reasons that loop constructs may be preferred to recursion.

Answer (score 4):

Quite often automatic storage (the stack) is bounded.  50,000 recursions is a lot.

If your stack is a mere 1 MB, and the entire function call overhead breaks 20 bytes, you will blow your stack.

`stringstream` is just a class that does things on creation and destruction, so it will read to and write to beyond the top of the stack.

To fix this, don't recurse 50k deep.  Or, increase your stack size (it will be a compiler flag).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, apparently the 50000 `ostringstream` instances blow up the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of *STACK* space. `s` is allocated on stack and you are doing it 50,000 times. Once you run OOM on your stack you crash (rightfully so)